# iOS Eddystone Beacon Problems - Can't find namespaceid

Tags: ios, ibeacon, uuid, eddystone

I'm trying to build an Eddystone beacon scanner. I have installed the Eddystone framework and this works fine. But I don't know which namespaceid my beacon has.

I installed an app named "eBeacon" from the store and there I have scanned my beacon successfully. They give me the id: 051674047A2B7D9D0A6F96BAEE9DBC3B

```
    // filter by namespace
    let namespaceUID = ESTEddystoneUID(namespaceID: "051674047A2B7D9D0A6F")
    let namespaceFilter = ESTEddystoneFilterUID(namespaceID: "051674047A2B7D9D0A6F")
    self.eddystoneManager.startEddystoneDiscovery(with: namespaceFilter)

    // filter by namespace and instance
    let namespaceInstanceUID = ESTEddystoneUID(namespaceID: "051674047A2B7D9D0A6F",
                                               instanceID: "96BAEE9DBC3B")
    let namespaceInstanceFilter = ESTEddystoneFilterUID(namespaceID: "051674047A2B7D9D0A6F96BAEE9DBC3B")
    self.eddystoneManager.startEddystoneDiscovery(with: namespaceInstanceFilter)

    // filter by URL
    let urlFilter = ESTEddystoneFilterURL(url: "http://www.wellcoressd.com")
    self.eddystoneManager.startEddystoneDiscovery(with: urlFilter)

    // filter by domain name
    let domainNameFilter = ESTEddystoneFilterURLDomain(urlDomain: "my.restaurant.com")
    self.eddystoneManager.startEddystoneDiscovery(with: domainNameFilter)

    func eddystoneManager(manager: ESTEddystoneManager, didDiscover eddystones: [ESTEddystone], with eddystoneFilter: ESTEddystoneFilter?) {
        print("yes")
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An Eddystone-UID namespace id should be 10 bytes and an instance id 6 bytes.

The value you show in the question, 051674047A2B7D9D0A6F96BAEE9DBC3B is 16 bytes, so I suspect this is the combination of both identifiers.  If this is correct:

```
namespace id: 051674047A2B7D9D0A6F
instance id: 96BAEE9DBC3B
```

You might try using my free Locate app which will scan Eddystone UID beacons and show you the namespace and instance identifiers separately.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have try it with your app but its not work they still stand in the cell looking for beacons.. after 10 min i closed the app

Comment: which sdk have you used to connect an Eddystone beacon?